# What is the state of art production search algorithm right now for semantic search? LSH? or other clustering method?

Tags: word-embeddings, search

Trying to implement semantic search for high cardinality embedding for my own learning purpose, so far [LSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) seems promising, but I am wondering what is the state of algorithm big tech company are using right now